# Datatable error , printing cannot read property 'row' of undefined in console

Tags: jquery, datatables

i have three ajax call. and with the first ajax i am filling the table initially, then with my second and third ajax, i am entering into the table again but this prob arises of row undefined. in my code i am trying to find that row for which this id matches and enter into it . but i am unable to do so.

```js
alert("C");
$(document).ready(function($) {
  table = $('#weeklysummary').DataTable(); {
    $.ajax({
      url: "xyz.php",
      success: function(queryResult) {
        alert("B");
        rowData = JSON.parse(queryResult);
        console.log(rowData);
        for (var i = 0; i < rowData.length; i++) {
          if (rowData[i].rental_status == "active") {
            table.row.add([
              rowData[i].id,
              rowData[i].name,
              rowData[i].day,
              " ",
              " ",
              rowData[i].attendence,
              " ",
            ]).draw(false);
          }

        }

      }
    });
    $.ajax({
      url: "abc.php",
      success: function(online_time_received) {
        alert("A");
        var time2 = JSON.parse(online_time_received);
        temp4 = Object.keys(time2);
        temp3 = Object.values(time2);
        console.log(temp4);
        console.log(temp3);
        for (i = 0; i <= temp4.length; i++) {
          var column = $('#weeklysummary').dataTable().fnFindCellRowIndexes(temp4[i], 0)
          table
            .cell(column, 4)
            .data(temp3[i])
            .draw(false);
        }
      }
    });
    $.ajax({
      url: "efg.php",
      success: function(value_received) {
        //alert("D");
        var last_time = JSON.parse(value_received);
        temp = Object.keys(last_synctime_for_rentals);
        temp2 = Object.values(last_synctime_for_rentals);
        console.log(temp);
        for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
          var column = $('#weeklysummary').dataTable().fnFindCellRowIndexes(temp[i], 0)
          table
            .cell(column, 3)
            .data(temp2[i])
            .draw(false);
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: The problem is at this line: table.row.add. Are you sure it should not be table.rows.add ?

Comment: i am a newbie coder not too sure but wait. i will try and let you know.

Comment: hey table.add.row works. i am able to enter the elemnts to the table but   var column = $('#weeklysummary').dataTable().fnFindCellRowIndexes(temp4[i], 0)
          table
            .cell(column, 4)
            .data(temp3[i])
            .draw(false); causes prob

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is? Is it an error in the Console? Or a server-side error? Or a behavioral problem of your datatable?

Comment: this is an error in the console.not server side. it is happening in the client side and this error keeps displaying in the console whenever i try to use the fnFindCellRowIndexes() to find the specific cell having the same value as that provided in parameter and plot against it. but  shows  cannot read property 'row of undefined

Comment: Please create a reproducible example. Without that I will not be able to help you.